# How to install pre-release packages with Lerna and Yarn?

Tags: node.js, yarnpkg, lerna, monorepo

I have a monorepo setup with Lerna and Yarn. I would like to install and use some pre-release packages from a third party project into my monorepo and after some time I would like to switch to the "release" versions of those third party packages.

Is these an easy way to achieve this without the need to change the package.json files manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Simply put you cannot do it with yarn. You can read a long discussion about it  [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/1743)

But as you can use npm for this with `--no-save` option. This will not change your `package.json` or `yarn.lock` file.